# Python How to pass continuous generated data stream between methods

Tags: python, kafka-python, data-stream

I have a method that continuously generates data and prints them on the console. Let's say something simple like generating random number:

```
def number_generator():
    while True:
        random.randint(1,100)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return
```

I have a separate method that is supposed to take ths input and write this data to a Kafka topic.

How can I pass this data stream from `number_generator()` into another method.

P.S: I know I can just write the Kafka `send()` to topic method within `number_generator()` but I am to learning Python and was curious how data streams can be passed between methods, if they can be.

Answer (score 0):

To create a generator in python, you use the `yield` keyword:

```
def number_generator():
    while True:
        yield random.randint(1,100)
```

Then, you can instantiate this generator and pass it to a function which is intended to consume it, for example:

```
def print10(gen):
    n = 0
    for val in gen:
        print(val)
        n += 1
        if n >= 10:
            break

print10(number_generator())
```

Answer (score 0):

They way I understand your question you implicitly assuming some kind of multi threading or multi tasking. The easiest way however is keeping close to the name of your function and use a generator pattern:

```
def number_generator():
    while True:
        value = random.randint(1,100)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        yield value

gen = number_generator()
for num in gen:
    # do something
    print(num)
```

If you want to have the generator and worker run concurrently, you can use `asyncio`. This makes sense if wour worker also needs some time e.g. to fetch something from a socket. In this wait time the generator can now already fetch the next job.

```
import random
import asyncio

class my_async_generator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.counter >= 10:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.counter += 1
        value = random.randint(1,100)
        return value
    
async def worker(item):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(item)


async def do_async_stuff():
    tasks = []
    async for num in my_async_generator():
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(num)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(do_async_stuff())
```

Then you still have multi-tasking, which in the context of cpython ist not so much helpfull due to the GIL (global interpreter lock) and multi-processing. But for that you will need some kind of communication between the threads, because they don't share the same memory space anymore.